# How Find The Closest Places apps work

Tags: java, android, google-apps

I'm new to android app programming , and i'm looking to built an app which find the closest (specific) places to a user . i have some java programming skills but i don't know how  and where to begin .

Comment: try google places api https://developers.google.com/places/

Comment: Look for android tutorials like this one for example.
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html
Then you need to use GPS to locate the user and so on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use [LocationServices](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationServices.html) to fetch the user's [current location](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)
2. [SignUp](https://developers.google.com/places/android/signup) for Google API Console and create a key for Places API
3. Now you can use [Places API for Android](https://developers.google.com/places/android/start) to get direct results or use [Places API for Web](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/intro) to make web request in background and parse JSON result.

Comment: Check answer of @Rajan that is an example of Places API for Web

Comment: Thank you this was helpful :) 

sorry i can't rate your answer ... i'm have not  reached 15 reputation yet :/

Answer (score 0):

I would like to Share One Link in which You should have to pass custom location and few words like Restaurant,cafe,food,Bar etc. and You got a result of nearest Place as follows:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=23.0127038,72.5110915&radius=100000&types=home_goods_store&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyDZmSN7R_YXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

In Above link supply the location parameter with your Own,
types parameter with above category,
Your Custom Browser Key .

Answer (score -1):

As mentiones by Ankit Bansal, if you dont know the locations around you, then you can use the places api, if you know the locations or are custom locations then you can use the [directions api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) from Google, whit it you can specify a start and end points (latitude, longitude) and obtain all several data about the route to follow, including the distance and time to arrive.

If you also need to compare between some places to check which one is the closest you can try this:
First try to get a small set of places to compare, use some kind of raw selection at first, maybe euclidean distance. Then launch the request to the different routes to the directions api and compare the distance/time between those routes.

Comment: Actually you don't need directions to find closest place.. just send the `radius` parameter and `order by distance` in the Places API web request and you will get the list of places in ascending order of distance

Comment: As mentioned the directions api would be only in case of some custom locations, maybe user selected locations that would not be registered on places api. However for general purpose the places api is better. =)